# How to make automatic scrolling to the desired word in the text

Tags: javascript, angular, textarea

When I move from searching to the desired word in textarea where there is a large text, I already have the first index of this word and the last index.With this I do `setSelectionRange (firstIndex, lastIndex)` and `focus ()`.

But the problem is that automatic scrolling to this word does not work and you need to scroll manually to see the highlighted word. How to solve this?
[image: Search results]
[image: Selected word and scroll bar]

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const subscription = this.pageService.subject.subscribe(
      r => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.textareaNovel.nativeElement.focus();
          const firstIndex = this.pageService.allIndex[this.pageService.indexOfOne];
          const lastIndex = firstIndex + this.pageService.inputSearchText.length;
          this.textareaNovel.nativeElement.setSelectionRange(firstIndex,lastIndex);
        }, 100);
      },
      e => console.error(e),
      () => console.info("completed")
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

var objDiv = document.getElementById("divExample");
objDiv.scrollTop = 50

You can use this to scroll wherever you would like, if you can find the text position you can just plug it in. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, but problem is that in textarea no <div> inside. I know only indexes of word